# Pop-up window when clicking on an image in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question has been asked before, but mine is a little different.

I know tthat to do a popup of a thumbnail i have to use Javascript and give te image location.  however, what i want to do is this;

```
<IMG SRC="test.png" ALT="test1" WIDTH=32 HEIGHT=32 onclick="openWin(test.png)"></a>
```

where test.PNG is a picture i just queried from the database in SQLPLUS.  i do not have a local copy and i do not know the path to id.  when i write the javascript function for this, i wrote:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function openWin(img) {
    window.open(img);

}
</script>
```

however, i keep getting a URL\image.png does not exist.  How can i get this working?  it has to work for an arbitrary number of images, depending on how many actually meet the requirements of the query.

the test.png does not actually exist, i wanted to see becuase it shows as a broken image icon in my table, but when i click on it, it says the URL does not exist.

Comment: Your HTML code is awful. Use lowercase html tags, surround attribute with  quotes, separate `onclick` from html tags, surround string values with single quotes, stray `</a>` tag found and the `language="JavaScript"` has been deprecated for years. Ouch.

Comment: So you're trying to load an image that doesn't exist, and you don't like receiving an error that it doesn't exist? That's how it's supposed to work! If you don't want the error, don't attach an `onclick` handler for images which don't exist.

Comment: i understand the image does not exist. what i want to do is have the broken thumbnail icon i get in my table that tells me the image is not there and make it bigger when i click on it.  that way, when i have an actual image, it will make it bigger on click

Answer (score 2):

Screw Javascript. You don't need Javascript for this. Lose the 'onclick' and put 'target="_Blank"' in an 'href' tag around the 'img' tag.

Example:

```html
<a href="YourLink" target="_Blank">
    <img src="test.png" alt="Put something more exciting here." width="32" height="32" />
</a>
```

All good? By the way, this isn't PHP, my friend. Hehe. Wrong hashtag.

Comment: thanks.   uhm.  I am not sure what i should put in the "your link" section. i dont really have a link. i would be getting the image from a database. but this is what i wanted.  I just ned to figure out how to resize it.

Comment: Everything on the internet has a direct URL that keeps everything linked. In the "your link" section, you would put the direct URL to the image or webpage that you want your user to be source to upon click. [Example: If you want to link to your image directly, you would insert... " http://www.YourWebsite.com/images/YourImage.jpg ", and it would be the exact same link that you put inside your SRC.]

You need the direct URL to your image, if you're going to source it. Every linked action within code requires the designation of a path/link/url, and if you don't have the path, then you're screwed.

Comment: You mention that you're getting this image from a database. Is what you're doing legal? Is the image your property and are you sourcing it from your own web host, or are you using someone else's? If you're trying to link a picture that isn't yours off of a website that you have no permission linking to, then what you are doing is called server-theft. If you have permission to use the image, then download it to your own computer and reload it up on a free image hosting website, like Photobucket.com or PostImage.org . When you load it to one of these sites, they'll provide you with your own URL.

Comment: @Dota-Pengwin: I didn't mention your name in my last two posts, so be sure to see them. As for resizing, you can do that via either two ways: Download the image to your own computer and resize it using a basic image editing program, or just adjust the "width=" and "height=" attributes to what you need. I wouldn't recommend this second method, personally, because it can result in quality reduction, but it's still an option.

Comment: thank you that makes sense.  understand now.  I am very new to this and your help was greatly appreciated.